# Go XML suppression of automatically generated tags?

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement an XML format under Go that was originally written in Fortran. The format is already specified so I'm not free to make changes to the standard. Unfortunately, the format includes data that is not enclosed by an XML tag, thus I would like to suppress the automatic tag creation provided by xml.Marshal.

I've investigated all the standard option associated with marshalling,as documented at : https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/

By default marshalling will use the structure variable name, which can be overridden by the `xml:` definition. As far as I can tell there is no definition that suppresses the tag name.

```
type SAO_FREQUENCY_LIST struct {
    Type string     `xml:",attr"`
    SigFig int      `xml:",attr"`
    Units string        `xml:",attr"`
    Description string  `xml:",attr"`
    Frequencies string  `xml:""`
}
```

I want the XML output to be as follows:

```
<FrequencyList Type="float" SigFig="5" Units="MHz" Description="Nominal Frequency">
    3.7 3.8
</FrequencyList>"
```

By default xml.MarshalIndent(..) yields:

```
<FrequencyList Type="float" SigFig="5" Units="MHz" Description="”Nominal Frequency">
     <Frequencies>3.7 3.8</Frequencies>
</FrequencyList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `,chardata` modifier to indicate that the value of a struct member should be used as character data for the XML element.  For your example, this would be:

```
type FrequencyList struct {
    ...
    Frequencies string  `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

You can experiment with an example using this change here: https://play.golang.org/p/oBa8HuE-57d